# How can I center my caption with a non-centered image?

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to align the caption to the center of the image, while having the image aligned to the (default) left of the page.
Instead, what's happening is that my image is where I want it, but my text is aligned to the center of the web page, instead of the center of the image.

```css
.image .caption {
  font-size: x-small;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="image">
  <caption align="bottom" class="caption">Mary Magdalene’s supposed skull on display in Southern France.<br> Copyright © 2021 Magdalene Publishing</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="post003.html"><img src="disn_d5xcaazpjz-1-1.jpg" alt="Mary Magdalene’s skull on 
                display in France" /></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of your requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many solutions could work here. You could use flexbox, absolute positioning, or `display: grid;` like I did here.

Using `place-items: center` on the grid parent element you can then select your caption and table body and set their grid area to the same area : `1 / 1 / 1 / 1`

Other than that, I put a white background on the caption for readability. Also, I just wanted to say you have quite the photo to be displaying. So I replaced it with some cute cats.

```css
.image {
  display:grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: min-content;
}
tbody, .caption {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1;
}
.image .caption {
  background: white;
  font-size: x-small;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="image">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="post003.html"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/07/19/20/11/kitten-6479019_960_720.jpg" width="400" alt="Some cute kittens" /></a></td>
  </tr>
    <caption align="bottom" class="caption">Cute kittens photo<br>
    Copyright © Pixabay</caption>
</table>
```